# Benefits of creating a new workspace for each project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I'm new to Eclipse. Still trying to understand the usefulness of workspaces. Why would/wouldn't I create a new workspace for each project? My instinct is to create a new workspace for each project because I like to have my projects fully encapsulated, but this seems to be atypical.

Answer (score 4):

Simply put, there aren't enough advantages to having a separate workspace for each project to justify it.

But here's something practical to consider: do you ever need to reference files or code from one project while you're working on another?  I know I do that all the time, and that wouldn't be easy to do with isolated workspaces.

Answer (score 4):

I make a workspace for every project, as Eclipse takes ~45 minutes to build my company's app and you cannot do anything useful while that happens (i.e. save files, change settings, do any sort of refactoring or autocomplete). I have multiple workspaces so I can use one while the other builds and vice-versa.